# Initialize ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I met a problem as follow:

When I initialize a `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`, the codes are:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> group = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
group.add((ArrayList<Integer>) Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
group.add((ArrayList<Integer>) Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6));
group.add((ArrayList<Integer>) Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9));
for (ArrayList<Integer> list : group) {
    for (Integer i : list) {
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Although the codes can be compiled successfully, I still get a exception on console:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:49)

Thanks for help !

Comment: This strikes me as something that should be caught at compilation time. What's with the forced cast?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` doesn't return a `java.util.ArrayList`. It *does* return an instance of a class called `ArrayList`, coincidentally - but that's not `java.util.ArrayList`.

Unless you *need* this to really be an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` I'd just change it to:

```
List<List<Integer>> group = new ArrayList<>();
group.add(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
group.add(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6));
group.add(Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9));
for (List<Integer> list : group) {
    ...
}
```

If you *do* need an `ArrayList<ArrayList<...>>` - or if you need to be able to add to the "inner" lists even if you don't need them with a static type of `ArrayList` - then you'll need to create a new `ArrayList` for each list:

```
group.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)));
// etc
```

Comment: @manouti: Doh! I copied that line specifically to do that... Done.

Answer (score 5):

The return of `Arrays.asList` is not a `java.util.ArrayList`; the `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` is a separate class, nested in `Arrays`, even if it's a `List`.

If you must have an `ArrayList`, then create another `ArrayList` yourself using the returned `List` from `Arrays.asList`, instead of casting, e.g.:

```
group.add(new ArrayList<Integer>( Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3) ));
```

Answer (score 4):

`Arrays.asList` returns an instance of a nested static type `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` that is different from `java.util.ArrayList`. You can avoid this problem by programming to the `List` interface (which `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` implements as well) and without the unneeded casts:

```
List<List<Integer>> group = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
group.add(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
group.add(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6));
group.add(Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9));
for (List<Integer> list : group) {
    for (Integer i : list) {
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
group.add(new ArrayList<Integer>((Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))));
group.add(new ArrayList<Integer>((Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6))));
group.add(new ArrayList<Integer>((Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9))));

for (ArrayList<Integer> arrayList : group) {
  for (Integer integer : arrayList) {
    System.out.println(integer);
  }
}
```

Please refer this code. This might help you out to achieve your requirement.

Comment: How does your answer really differ from the already accepted one?